# Can seller of property impose conditions on how it is used by the new owner?

Tags: contract-law, property, breach-of-contract, animals

When I sell a domestic animal, can I impose a condition that the animal is kept as a pet and never killed for meat? If the new owner breaches this condition, will I be able to hold them to account?

This would be analogous to [listed buildings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Listed_building): you can own them but you can't demolish or alter them significantly.

Jurisdiction: any English-speaking country.

Answer (score 2):

You generally have [freedom of contract](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_contract) so you can put whatever conditions you like on the sale.

In practice, a court would probably consider such a term a [collateral contract](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collateral_contract) so that a breach would not invalidate the main contract.

For your particular example, enforcement would be problematic: if they breach the term, what damage have you suffered?

Comment: The damage would be emotional only so hard to quantify. But if the condition was "if you kill the animal you pay me $1000 full stop", would I still have to prove damages?

Comment: @Greendrake that sounds like a penalty - penalties are unenforceable in a contract.

Comment: Some animal rescue organizations have restrictions--return animal to us, inspections. I don't know if they're enforceable.